# Fetching Tag Value in the given XML

Tags: xml, tags

I have an XML which has a Tag as below format.

```
<OrderReference orderID="1102" orderDate="2018-10-10T11:36:12Z">
```

I want to read order ID value and OrderDate Value, I have tried as below but not fetching the value for OrderID.

```
<OrderReference>.<orderID> 
<OrderReference ATTR=orderID>
```

Kindly suggest any other way where I can read the data for the Tags from given XML in this format.

Comment: What technology/programming environment are you in? I don't recognize your attempt as anything resembling a language that I know.

Comment: i will get the xml from client, and have to map this xml tags with our gateway to import the data from xml which we receive to our instance.